# We-intentions and the kingdom-of-ends version of the categorical imperative

Tags: ethics, kant, theology, categorical-imperative, intentionality

One of Allen Wood's most finely ground axes was his contention that, notwithstanding certain translations/interpretations of Kant's writings on categorical imperatives, the three primary formulations are *not* equivalent, either intrinsically or in application. I found Wood's tone unhappily reminiscent of G. E. Moore or Michael Huemer, however, so I wondered if his own weird biases had clouded his picture of the CI too much. I later found it easier to deny the "doctrine" of a threefold CI, or a strict such unfolding, altogether (Kant could not have claimed to *know* that a transcendental/noumenal object like the moral law, *must unfold* in three ways rather than four, or five, or whatever-many number of times).

Still, I was also wondering about the difference between, "I ought to..." and, "*We* ought to..." and so I in turn wonder whether Kant's *kingdom-of-ends* version of the CI might be styled a [we-intentional](https://iep.utm.edu/collective-intentionality/#SH3a) representation, contrasted with the law-of-nature formulation as, "*I* ought to act only on that maxim that can be willed as a universal law," or with the end-in-itself formula covering a [*second-personal*](https://www.hup.harvard.edu/catalog.php?isbn=9780674034624) deontic interlocution: "*You* ought to..."

Regarding the you-intentional mode of the CI, two main things. (A) We can appeal to Hannah Arendt's talk of interior dialogue, of discourse by "myself with myself," as a case of addressing ourselves second-personally: so here the CI might be expressed as, "*You and I* ought to..." (B) More importantly for present purposes, if the different CI formulae "evolve from one another" (or however we might want to put it), then a plausible evolutionary dynamic manifests in the transition from first-personal singular to first-person plural perspectives: "I ought to..." covers cases where we are alone, but with an eye towards the universality of, "We ought to...": the abstract picture of a "law of nature" autonomously conducted as our part in the music of deontic existence is satisfiable by a lone agent; but as we are socialized and discern the real problem of moral disagreement and intersubjectivity and the rest, we find that we can truly will things under the image of, "We ought to..." And so there is a circuit, *I-ought goes to you-and-I-ought, which goes to we-ought*, in which each version of the CI is the same "ought," yet the versions are not identical.

**Can Kant's situation of the role for divine agency in the kingdom of ends be incorporated into a we-intentional CI?** He says that God is not under obligations, since God's will is absolutely rational, whereas for us the moral law is an, "I ought to..." instead of an, "I *would*... if I were absolutely rational." However, if in saying, "We ought to..." while including God under "We," are we attributing our collective duty to each member *per se*, or is there room for God's role in, "We ought to..." to be that of the outside arbiter, nevertheless "friends with us" (c.f. Kant's talk of the "friend of humanity")?

Comment: This is close to Allison's analysis of intra-personal universalisation in the first formulation vs. inter-personal universalisation in the kingdom of ends formulation (see his commentary, chapter 9). I'd be careful to put divine will and CI together, though. The former by definition does *will* the same but as you yourself point out *never* via the detour of having to question one's maxims or be coerced by reason.

Comment: According to Zeno the Stoic founder (relatively) valuable individual action as *I ought to* is completely exclusive with moral (virtue) action as *we ought to*, using Kant's term the former could be the everyday individual hypothetical imperative (HI) instead of CI. A person could entangle herself in the former during her whole life without any consideration for the latter. Since everyone's situation and context is always different, thus {moral CIs/precepts} are always amorphous, misinterpreted and mysterious for most people when they're hidden and bracketed in those revealed actions...

Comment: @PhilipKlöcking, I also forgot the place where Kant says that "God does not with the world make up a whole." If this applies to social parts/wholes, then God's separate *office* in the kingdom of ends, vs. our office, keeps God's will from factoring too readily into the situation, perhaps.

Comment: If we want to be a bit cynical, since God's will should be bound to intellectual intuition and thus be "pure actuality" in a sense, ie. necessarily actualize the good, Kant's God probably does not want much at all anymore.